# Do infinite primes $p$ exist of the form $p \bmod 10^{n-1}...\bmod 10^1$ where each $\bmod$ itself is prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Define $n$ to be the number of digits in $p$ and no primes can have a $0$ digit.

**Example 1**

Let $p=1223, n=4$, then

$p \bmod 10^3 \bmod 10^2 \bmod 10^1$

Each successive $\bmod$ is prime

```
 223
  23
   3
```

**Example 2**

Let $p=8499636997, n=10$, then

$p \bmod 10^9 \bmod 10^8  \ldots \bmod 10^2 \bmod 10^1 $

Each successive $\bmod$ is prime

```
 499636997
  99636997
   9636997
    636997
     36997
      6997
       997
        97
         7
```

**Question**

Lots of these primes have dead end paths.

For example, $p=8612649613$

```
Primes                         No Primes
---------------------------    -----------------
8612649613 -> [3]8612649613 -> [1...9]38612649613
8612649613 -> [9]8612649613 -> [1...9]98612649613
```

Most likely these primes become very sparse or cease to exist?

Comment: They're called [right-truncatable primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncatable_prime).

Comment: @jjagmath Nice, so that link says in "base 10, there are exactly 4260 left-truncatable primes, 83 right-truncatable primes, and 920,720,315 left-and-right-truncatable primes." So they do cease to exist eventually! :)